# Script that renames files to numbers skips some files

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, ubuntu-16.04

I have a script that renames all `.mp3` files in directory to consecutive numbers:

```
dir = os.getcwd() if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1] 
os.chdir(dir)
filenames_in_dir = os.listdir(dir)

mpr_search_expr = re.compile('.mp3')

currNumber = 0;
for filename in filenames_in_dir:
    # ignore non-mp3 files
    if mpr_search_expr.search(filename):
        #change title to number
        audiofile = eyed3.load(filename)
        audiofile.tag.title = get_valid_name_from_index(currNumber)
        audiofile.tag.save()

        #change name to number
        os.rename(filename, get_valid_name_from_index(currNumber))
        currNumber += 1
```

with names function defined as:

```
def get_valid_name_from_index(index):
'''index must be 0-based, return value is >=1'''
valid_name = str(index + 1) + '.mp3'

if index + 1 < 10 :
    valid_name = '0' + valid_name

return valid_name
```

The problem is, it seem to skip 22 or 21 element in the directory:
[image: skipped]

and it can skip both this number on different runs:

[image: skipped other number]

I can't find the bug...

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your for loop increment the value of `i` even for non mp3 files.

```
for i in range(len(filenames_in_dir)):
    # ignore non-mp3 files BUT INCREMENT value of i
    if mpr_search_expr.search(filenames_in_dir[i]):
        os.rename(filenames_in_dir[i], get_valid_name_from_index(i))
```

you should do something like

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(filenames_in_dir)):
    # ignore non-mp3 files
    if mpr_search_expr.search(filenames_in_dir[i]):
        j+= 1
        os.rename(filenames_in_dir[i], get_valid_name_from_index(j))
```

Comment: The problem is still the same? I don't understand. You may still have a problem, but the output should has changed since the script changed.

Comment: NB: If it answers your question then please check it as "correct answer", but don't delete it...